# How to change post categories with a script (PHP, Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with two categories (Silver, Gold)

The posts start out as Gold but I want them to automatically be added to the Silver category after 48 hours. How could I write a script to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple plugin, or a wp-cron based function.  In that plugin/function you should query a list of posts older than 48 hours.  You can use [*cat* or *category_name*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) arguments to query "Gold" posts, and [time filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) to query posts older than 48 hours (scroll down to the "Return posts from the last 30 days" snippet, it does exactly what you want, just tweak it a little bit and replace days with hours).

After that you can iterate thru Gold posts and use [wp_set_post_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories) function to overwrite category to Silver.